# Pass currency event in Dynamic Tag Management?

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am trying to use currency event in my site and want to capture same using DTM. 
But in DTM, I could not locate any option to set currency event. Can someone please help me on this.

Here is my scenario:
Let's say, I have a Javascript on the page code as:

var digitalData = {
                'Amount': 1000
                  }

Then in DTM data element, can this numeric value be passed, by writing this in the Path: 'digitalData.Amount' (after selecting 'Type' as JS Object in Data Elements)

Also, even if we capture this information in Data Element, how do I set this value in any currency success event (for eg event20) in the page load rule section in DTM ? Do I have to write any custom script for that ? If yes, please give me some example, how to do it.

Thanks in advance,
Adi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set a data element just how you said - assuming that `digitalData` is a globally scoped variable, available when DTM evaluates data elements. If it is not, then the data element won't be set.

That aside, DTM currently only lets you set `s.events` with a regular event.  It does not let you do currency or numeric event syntax.  In order to do this, you will need to open up the custom code section and set `s.events` yourself, and you can use `_satellite.getVar('data_element_name')` to reference the data element (replace `data_element_name` with the name of your data element).

Comment: Thanks much Crayon. I will let you know if I face any further challenge.

Comment: Hi Crayon, I have this code: 


`var s=window.s;
var amount = _satellite.getVar('Amt'); 
s.events= "event1=amount";`


'Amt' data Element would capture the numeric value of amount from the page. 
But this code is not working obviously, because event1 has been defined as currency event and amount would be of 'var' type.


Please suggest me correct way to assign numeric value to currency success event.

Thanks

Comment: @Adi javascript doesn't parse variables inside strings. You need to do `s.events="event1="+amount;`